# Redirecting to other page gives me 500 internal server error in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I am performing search task in my project. In which i have to call API for the result. But before that i have to check whether any state is passed into props or not.If props have any state then call api otherwise redirect us to homepage.On local server it's working fine but on server it gives me 500 internal server error when no props state is passed.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setProcess(false)
  setResults([])
  console.log(props.location)
  if (props.location.state !== undefined) {
    ApiService.searchApi(props.location.state.search, filter).then(response => {
      setResults(response.data.results)
      setProcess(true)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("error", error)
    })
  } else {
    //when props state is undefined redirect to homepage
    history.push("./")
  }
}, [filter])
```

Comment: What do your server error logs say about the 500 response?

Comment: a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: No, that's the error presented to the client (you / your browser). What do the **server error logs** say?

Answer (score 0):

One of the scenario where you get a 500 status error is when the request object is incorrect when passed inside an API. So take a look at your request object on how it is going when you are sending it to the server. Since you mentioned, it's working fine on local, I hope you mean it's a local environment where the api is also available. The other scenario could be api might not be deployed properly on the server side. You can try checking either of the options.

Attachments Attached
[image: When I missed out the input attributes in request object]

[image: When the Input Object is Correct]

Comment: The error was basically due to absence of .httpaccess file .Now my project is redirecting accurately.